# Method not found: void Facebook.CoreKit.AppEvents.ActivateApp()

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

My Xamarin.iOS app was working fine until I deleted some packages that I didn't need anymore, and were preventing my app to build. Now my app builds, but it crashes on startup. In the application output:

> Method not found: void Facebook.CoreKit.AppEvents.ActivateApp()

I have these packages still installed and up-to-date:

Xamarin.Facebook.CoreKit.iOS
Xamarin.Facebook.CoreKit.CoreKit.iOS
Xamarin.Facebook.GamingServiceKit.iOS
Xamarin.Facebook.LoginKit.iOS
Xamarin.Facebook.MarketingKit.iOS
Xamarin.Facebook.PlaceKit.iOS
Xamarin.Facebook.ShareKit.iOS

I am calling `FacebookClientManager.Initialize(application, launchOptions)` in my `FinishedLaunching` and `FacebookClientManager.OnActivated()` in my `OnActivated`

Comment: Try removing those nugets from solution. Then add them back in.

Comment: That worked. I uninstalled the `Plugin.FacebookClient` package, and everything that came with it, and installed the `Plugin.FacebookClient` only and it doesn't crash anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing those nugets from solution. Then add them back in.